# Find four numbers in a list that add up to a target value

Tags: python, algorithm, list, list-comprehension, duplicates

Below is the code I wrote in an attempt to solve this problem: Find four numbers in a list that add up to `x`.

```
def sum_of_four(mylist, x):
    twoSum = {i+j:[i,j] for i in mylist for j in mylist}
    four = [twoSum[i]+twoSum[x-i] for i in twoSum if x-i in twoSum]
    print four
sum_of_four([2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 8], 8)
```

The answer I get for the sample input is:

```
[[1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1]]
```

However, this list of lists contains duplicates. For example, `[1,1,3,3]` is the same as `[3,3,1,1]`.

How can I print the list of lists without duplicate lists? I want to be as efficient as possible in runtime and space. Is it possible to change my list comprehension so that I don't print duplicates? I certainly do not want to sort the lists and then use `set()` to delete duplicates. I want to do something better.

Comment: This question screams "dynamic programming".  But at the very least, you could implement a recursive solution that pulls a number from the list and attempts a sum (of three, then two, then one) on the list that follows that number.  You'll get better efficiency if you sort the list first.  You can avoid duplicates by not recursing twice on the same number.

Comment: Should that be a list of unique numbers?

Comment: There is only one `3` in the input set. Is `1,1,3,3` even a correct answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @tnecniv how do you think of having a list of non-repeating inner lists where the input numbers are repeating?

Comment: You could find all combinations of 4 items (without replacement) from the input list and select only those that sum to x. itertools.combinations(iterable, r) generates all combinations of r items from iterable in sorted order iff iterable is sorted.  This may be rather brute force, but its easy to code and so is efficient in terms of programming time.

Comment: Simplest way would be to use a Set(). Said simple not most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A correct and relatively efficient approach starts by counting the number of times each value occurs in the input list. Suppose `value` occurs `count` times. Then you can append up to `count` copies of `value` to a list in which you build a selection of values. Before appending any copies of `value`, and after appending each copy, make a recursive call to move on to the next value.

We can implement this approach as follows:

```
length = 4

# Requires that frequencies be a list of (value, count) sorted by value.
def doit(frequencies, index, selection, sum, target, selections):
  if index == len(frequencies):
    return
  doit(frequencies, index + 1, selection[:], sum, target, selections)  # Skip this value.
  value, count = frequencies[index]
  for i in range(count):
    selection.append(value)
    sum += value
    if sum > target:
      return  # Quit early because all remaining values can only be bigger.
    if len(selection) == length:
      if sum == target:
        selections.append(selection)
      return  # Quit because the selection can only get longer.
    doit(frequencies, index + 1, selection[:], sum, target, selections)  # Use these values.

def sum_of_length(values, target):
  frequency = {}
  for value in values:
    frequency[value] = frequency.setdefault(value, 0) + 1
  frequencies = sorted(frequency.items())  # Sorting allows for a more efficient search.
  print('frequencies:', frequencies)
  selections = []
  doit(frequencies, 0, [], 0, target, selections)
  return list(reversed(selections))

print(sum_of_length([2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 8], 8))
print(sum_of_length([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], 8))
print(sum_of_length([-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 3))
```

By the way, the correct answer for your sample input is `[[1, 1, 2, 4]]`. There is only one way to select four elements from `[2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 8]` such that their sum is 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the numbers more than once such as your sample answer where you only have one `3` in the list but you have `[1,1,3,3]` as a solution, then you can try:

```
def sum_of_four(list, x, y, curr=[]):
if y == 1:
    for l in list:
        if l == x:
            d = curr[:]
            d.append(l)
            print(d)
            break
else:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        l = list[i]
        if l <= (x - l) / (y - 1):
            d = curr[:]
            d.append(l)
            sum_of_four(list[i:], x-l, y-1, d)

sum_of_four(sorted([2,4,1,4,6,3,8]),8,4)
```